# List split in Elm

Tags: elm

**Write a function to split a list into two lists. The length of the first part is specified by the caller.**

I am new to Elm so I am not sure if my reasoning is correct. I think that I need to transform the input list in an array so I am able to slice it by the provided input number. I am struggling a bit with the syntax as well. Here is my code so far:

```
listSplit: List a -> Int -> List(List a)
listSplit inputList nr = 
let myArray = Array.fromList inputList
    in Array.slice 0 nr myArray
```

So I am thinking to return a list containing 2 lists(first one of the specified length), but I am stuck in the syntax. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alternative implementation:

```
split : Int -> List a -> (List a, List a)
split i xs =
    (List.take i xs, List.drop i xs)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll venture a simple recursive definition, since a big part of learning functional programming is understanding recursion (which foldl is just an abstraction of):

```
split : Int -> List a -> (List a, List a)
split splitPoint inputList =
    splitHelper splitPoint inputList []

{- We use a typical trick here, where we define a helper function 
that requires some additional arguments. -}
splitHelper : Int -> List a -> List a -> (List a, List a)
splitHelper splitPoint inputList leftSplitList =
     case inputList of
         [] ->
             -- This is a base case, we end here if we ran out of elements
             (List.reverse leftSplitList, [])

         head :: tail ->
              if splitPoint > 0 then
                    -- This is the recursive case
                    -- Note the typical trick here: we are shuffling elements
                    -- from the input list and putting them onto the
                    -- leftSplitList.
                    -- This will reverse the list, so we need to reverse it back
                    -- in the base cases
                    splitHelper (splitPoint - 1) tail (head :: leftSplitList)
               else
                    -- here we got to the split point,
                    -- so the rest of the list is the output
                    (List.reverse leftSplitList, inputList)
```

Comment: The performance profile of this implementation is similar to the take/drop implementation. It has the benefit of being a tail-recursive implementation that compiles to a very efficient white loop.

Answer (score 3):

Use `List.foldl`

```
split : Int -> List a -> (List a, List a)
split i xs =
  let
    f : a -> (List a, List a) -> (List a, List a)
    f x (p, q) =
      if List.length p >= i then
        (p, q++[x])
      else
        (p++[x], q)
  in
    List.foldl f ([], []) xs
```

- When list `p` reaches the desired length, append element `x` to the second list `q`.
- Append element `x` to list `p` otherwise.

Normally in Elm, you use `List` for a sequence of values. `Array` is used specifically for fast indexing access.

When dealing with lists in functional programming, try to think in terms of `map`, `filter`, and `fold`. They should be all you need.

To return a pair of something (e.g. two lists), use tuple. Elm supports tuples of up to three elements.

Additionally, there is a function [splitAt](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/latest/List-Extra#splitAt) in the [List.Extra](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/list-extra/8.2.4/List-Extra) package that does exactly the same thing, although it is better to roll your own for the purpose of learning.

Comment: Thank you for the help and explanation. One more question, for example for the case when removing the nth element from a list is this a case when an array comes more handy?

Comment: But Array does not have a `remove` function. It's more for `get` and `set` at a position. I think, for beginners, you are better off ignoring Array, and do everything with lists and get yourself comfortable with the basics. The perceived efficiency of Array simply does not matter at a beginner level.

Comment: Also note that this solution has a worse complexity bounds than the other solutions. This is O(*n²*), whereas the other solutions are O(*m*) where *n* is the length of the input list and *m* is the split size (*m* <= *n*).